# Näh-Fachbegriffe aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche

Tags: translation, english-to-german, colloquial

Ich will Covid-19-Masken nähen und brauche Hilfe beim Übersetzen ein paar technischer Fachbegriffe, um Stoff zu bestellen. Dafür gibt es mehrere Optionen.

Auf Englisch heißen diese Materialien:

1. finished fold over elastic
2. braided elastic
3. bias cut (Schrägschnitt, glaube ich) spandex, swimsuit material, or lycra

Z.B. sollte man nach schrägegeschnittenem Lycrastoff suchen oder nach Schrägschnittstoff?

Comment: Da würde ich mal die Hilfe der Übersetzer-Gemeinschaft auf www.proz.com nutzen. Dort gibt es auch ein Forum (Datenbank) für solche Fachtermini-Übersetzungen. Du kannst deine Fachbebriffe dort eingeben, und vermutlich wirst du recht schnell kompetente Antwort erhalten.

Comment: Wie viel kostet es?

Comment: Jeder der hier Offtopic voted, warum?

Comment: www.proz.com ist ein Internet-Portal zur gegenseitigen Hilfe (!) professioneller Übersetzer. Die Benützung kostet nichts. Du kannst dir eine Konto anlegen und Fragen stellen - zum Beispiel eben nach solchen Fachbegriffen. Du kannst auch anderen bei ihren Fragen helfen; wie hier bei german.stackexchange - nur eben speziell für solche Übersetzungsprobleme.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: na na, wir haben schon den Anspruch, besser zu sein, als ein externes Portal. User wegzuschicken finde ich irgendwie kontraproduktiv.

Comment: @ Takkat danke, ich stimme nit dir zu!

Comment: @takkat  Wir haben hier sehr viel Sprachkompetenz, aber ich habe bisher noch keine Fachperson für Terminologie des Schneidereiwesens hier getroffen. Überdies wollen wir hier ja gar keine Übersetzungsdienste anbieten, dachte ich? (Siehe Forenregeln) Mir schien der Verweis auf proz.com darum die beste Auskunft, die man - in Ermangelung des eigentlichen Vokabulars - geben kann.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: in welcher "Forenregel" steht, dass wir keine Übersetzungshilfen leisten wollen? Einzig "**bulk** translation requests" sind off topic...

Comment: @Takkat Eine der Begründungen für "off topic" lautet *Thus, requests for **proofreading, spell checking or translations of individual texts** are not a good fit here.* Man kann argumentieren, dass man in diesem Aspekt etwas großzügiger sein sollte (ich habe schon viele close-Anträge gesehen, die meiner Ansicht nach recht kleinlich waren), aber das würde wohl eine entsprechende Diskussion im Meta erfordern.

Answer (score 1):

> sollte man nach schrägeschnittem Lycrastoff suchen

nach **schräggeschnittenem Lycrastoff**, bzw. "Lycra Schrägschnitt", wegen Google.

---

Wobei das Schrägschneiden in diesem Fall Sache des Schneiders sein könnte. Oder willst Du die Teile schon vorgeschnitten?

Aus einem alten Bikinioberteil (swimsuit!) kann man also gleich zwei Stück fabrizieren; an jeden Gesichts-Cup musst Du nur noch einen Elastic-Band annähen.

Ich hoffe die Materialien sind erhältlich. "Stoffe und Textilien" wäre so der Eintrag im Branchenverzeichnis,

Comment: @ rastafile danke fuer die Antwort. Ich bin Anfanger, also die Sache sollen womoeglich vorgeschnitten sein.